# I want to know how to pass the address of an integer pointer and modify it by dereferencing,

Tags: c, pointers

I want to know how we could pass the address of a pointer and in the function call, we change its value by dereferencing.

```
int main(){
  int x=7;    
  int *p;  // pointer to integer    
  p=&x; 

  modify(&p);    //passing address of pointer to integer
}
```

For the function below, do we need one asterisk or two? and how to dereference is_

```
void modify(int *p){

}
```

Comment: please show how we can change the value of p so that it can be modified in main, pass by reference. thank you.

Comment: We need to use `void modify(int **p)`.

Comment: how do i change the value of it?

Comment: sorry im new to pointers

Comment: See this link :https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-reference-to-a-pointer-in-c/amp/

Comment: See the "pointer to pointer" section in the above link

Comment: i did but none of them show how to change the value when passing the address of interger pointer. so how would i modify it in this function?

Comment: they had a global variable in the example so i just want to know how to change the value to 50 for example?

Answer (score 1):

```
void modify(int **p)
{
   **p = 50;
}
```

Comment: Well I guess he wants to alter the pointer, that would be the only reason to pass a pointer to a pointer. So probably something like `*p = new int(5);`

Answer (score 0):

The variable `p` in `main` has type `int *`, so it's adddress has type `int **`.  That should be the type of the parameter to `modify`.

Then, assuming you want to modify `x`, you need to dereference the parameter `p` in `modify` twice:

```
void modify(int **p){
    **p = 50;
}
```